# Select most recent entry from database using LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I need to select the most recent date from my database table and store it in a variable. 
I'm not very familiar with linq to entities but I gave it a go myself however I only got so far.

This is how far I got:

```
IQueryable<DateTime> date = from ftp in ctn.FTPRuns
                            orderby ftp.LastRun descending
                            select ftp.LastRun;
```

Can anyone tell me how I can modify this query to just select the most recent entry. I have tried "select ftp.LastRun.First();" however this is not an option in intellisense for me.

any help would be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of what you have there (date) is an ordered IQueryable. You can just call `date.First()` to get the first one in that sequence.

Otherwise if you want to cut a step, wrap your query in brackets and call.First on it to just get the date.

```
DateTime date = (from ftp in ctn.FTPRuns  
                 orderby ftp.LastRun descending  
                 select ftp.LastRun).First();
```

You could otherwise use lambdas:

```
DateTime date = ctn.FTPRuns.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastRun).First().LastRun;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Richard, I will mark it as the correct answer once the time limit is up :)

Answer (score 1):

```
IQueryable<DateTime> dates = from ftp in ctn.FTPRuns
                             orderby ftp.LastRun descending
                             select ftp.LastRun;
DateTime date = dates.First();
```